# 301 redirect loop - how to put a limit on redirects

Tags: model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I am working on a MVC website where I have to redirect all URLs to a certain format for SEO and analytics reasons. I have some URLs linked to other processes running on the server (I'm not 100% sure how they are set up as I haven't worked on them) but they have to be partially capitalised e.g. www.mysite.com/WebPage otherwise they don't work and are forced to redirect to upper case. This then causes a redirect loop where the code implemented in the Global.asax redirects to lower case, which then get redirected to upper case, and back to lower and so on. I am using .net 4 and not 4.5 so unfortunately I can't use System.Web.Routing to try and solve the issue.

Currently I have implemented some filters that allow these URLs to be ignored, but I have to manually identify the URL and I know I am not aware of all of them.

The code I currently have in my Global.asax looks like:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = requested.URL.AbsolutePath.ToLower();
    if (path.Contains(//Filtered URLs)
    return;

    var url = Request.Url.ToString();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
    Response.AddHeader("Location", url.ToLower());
    Response.End();
}
```

I am hoping to be able to set a limit to the number of redirects to 5 or so redirects, so the requested URL is no longer sent to be lower case when it must be upper case.